# python spyder IDE 3.14 ( python 3.6) kernel restarts while running in debug mode

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, spyder

It looks like spyder IDE is pretty limited when it comes to debugging any scipy ML code as it is not possible to run scipy optimization methods or plotting libraries in debug mode. The kernel keeps on restarting . 
I am not sure how to debug my code  particularly the scipy.optimize.minimize method( i don't want to go inside the method to debug but just want to execute it in a loop of 10 and read the parameter theta). I can do it easily in Octave.

I am surprised that spyder python IDE  lacks proper debugging capabilities to this extend.I was reading a response in stackoverflow by the developer of Sypder dated approx 2 years back talking about improving the debugging capabilities. I am using spyder 3.4.1 with python 3.6 and unfortunately it is still not good. can someone please recommend a better IDE mode of debugging in python ? .

I have installed my python using Anaconda distribution which I thought is the best out there.  appreciate your help.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a bug in Spyder 3.1.4 that makes the kernel restart on step-by-step debugging. We fixed that in Spyder 3.2, which will be available next week.

Comment: About my previous comment (from two years ago), well, we made some progress to improve debugging in Spyder 3.2, but there's still a lot of work to do. Unfortunately this is a complex problem and only since 8 months ago we have the resources to start tackling it.

Comment: @Carolos Cordoba, thank you for your response. I will wait for next week then. I am stuck trying to debug why my optimization code does not work well in python while the same works like  charm in octave. The only way to get to the bottom is debugging line by line unfortunately . I will wait till I install 3.2 before we can update this question with the answer. Thank you for the good work though!. I understand it looks thankless when people complain about things that doesn't work and don't mention  about what works!. overall I love spyder except for debugger..

Comment: Yeah, the debugger is quite limited at the moment. I hope we can change that in Spyder 4 (to be released next year).

Comment: any suggestions how to get the debugger going in the interim. waiting for 4 will be long wait. what are the new features in 3.2?.

Comment: [These](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Beta-version-changelog#ipython-console) are the new features, basically plots and history browsing. There's nothing else users can do to improve our debugger in 3.2, sorry.

Comment: Will I be able to run a line-by-line debugger or execute till the breakpoint without the kernel restarting?

Comment: Yes, that will work again (it was working before 3.1.4 too, as I said).

Comment: Spyder 3.2 was released 6-7 hours ago, though it is not yet available through conda. I have not yet tested it to see if the debugger works again.